# How to Connect Wired Ethernet Devices to a Wireless Network?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

Is there a device that connects to an existing wireless network, and lets me share internet among several wired ethernet devices plugged into it?

I have a desktop and a networked storage device upstairs, and a desktop/printer/IP phone downstairs. The desktop upstairs is plugged into a wireless router, which is connected to the Internet modem.

I am looking for a device into which I'd be able to plug in my equipment downstairs, and establish a connection to the network upstairs without pulling a dedicated wire for the link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a [Wireless Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_bridge).

> A wireless bridge is a hardware component used to connect two or more
>   network segments (LANs or parts of a LAN) which are physically and
>   logically (by protocol) separated.

More info:

- [Understanding Wireless LAN Bridges](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/1563991)
- [What is Bridging Mode in Wi-Fi Networking?](http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/wirelessproducts/f/apbridgingmode.htm)